# CreatDirectory or Delete directory is slower than code

Tags: c#, system.io.file

Just a quick question if you can help me, please.
In C#, I am creating a directory, if it does not exist. In the next command, I am checking if the directory exists, I will copy some files.

The Problem is, to creating a new directory or Deleting it, takes time and slower than next code execution time.

The software gives an error of **"The folder does not exist "**. 
I used `Thread.Sleep(5000);` to wait 5 seconds before copying the content to the directory.

It seems to be working but I feel like that this is not how it's supposed to be done. Does anyone know better coding?

```
string logDirectoryPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\LogFiles";
if (!Directory.Exists(logDirectoryPath))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\LogFiles");
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

if (Directory.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\LogFiles"))
{
   var s = logDirectoryPath + "\\Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".txt";

   using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(s))
   {
      w.WriteLine("--");
      w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
      w.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} {DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()}");
   }
}
```

**//EDIT**
JUST thought maybe I should use a loop?

```
While(!Directory.Exists(logDirectoryPath))
{
      Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\LogFiles");
}
```

Comment: hrmm, obviously  `Directory.CreateDirectory` will create the directory before the next line of code executes. There is something more to this story

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use DirectoryInfo

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(#{PATHSTRING});
```

and use di.Exists to check it exists / di.Create() to create folder

and I'd like to recommend to use logDirectoryPath which you defined already.

like this

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(logDirectoryPath);

if ( !di.Exists ) {
    di.Create();
}
```

Comment: Hi Arphile. Thank you for your reply. I don't understand. It seems the similar code and Is DirectoryInfo faster than Directory? Because my issue is, before creating the directory,  next code checks is the directory created.

Comment: if this code also makes trouble, try to use async/await function to wait your directory created.